# While installing cordova in my system it is giving this proxy error. Can anyone tell me the solution?

Tags: cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi4Zr.png)

I am facing this problem while installing cordova in my system. can anyone tell me the solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself clearly telling that your system is running behind proxy settings. So disable proxy settings try to run following commands

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

if it don't work connect your pc with another network and install